# ck editor content does not displaying as html in frontend

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, ckeditor4

My website is in Laravel. I am makeing about-us page in ckeditor on the Admin side.On the admin end, it works fine. I save the content json_encoded in DB. Issue is that when i want to display it on the front end side it displays the content as string . Have a look at result
[image]

what i am doing in blade.php is here
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current output is escaped(*safe-printed*) by default, try printing the content by using:

```php
@if (isset($about?->about))
{!! json_decode($about->about) !!}
@endif
```

Read more: [Laravel Docs: Displaying Unescaped Data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data)